# What is the view of shankara vedantins on kundalini yoga?

Tags: advaita, yoga, tradition, adi-shankaracharya

There is a book which deals with spiritual pursuit of one of the pontiff of the sringeri sankara mutt

He has discussed his experiences on various subjects including kundalini yoga in this book

http://svfonline.net/yoga-enlightenment-and-perfection.html#

What is the overall view of sanakara vedanta on this subject?

Comment: Shankara was the master of Kundalini Yoga. Apart from that, he was also trained in *Mahavatar Baba Ji's Kriya Yoga* by himself directly when he was staying in *Varanasi*. I believe Shankara has written commentary on few of these too.